# Wix setAttribute in a forEach loop only firing once?

Tags: javascript, custom-element, velo, setattribute

So I'm trying to send some data I fetched from my database to a Custom Element in Wix. To communicate, I used `setAttribute` and `attributeChangedCallback` of course.

```
var fetchedData = await fetchData();

fetchedData.forEach(function (item, index) {
    console.log(item, index); //output is perfect: logs every single entry there is
    $w('#customElement1').setAttribute('data', index); //This however seems to only fire once, "11" is the only value getting alerted (see below)"
})
```

and

```
attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if(name === 'data') {
      alert(newValue); //output: '11' expected output: '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...'
    }
 }
 static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['data'];
 }
```

As you can see, I am sending the index of the item via I am fetching `setAttribute`. However, my output ist just "11", though it should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7... What is the problem here? Is the `attributeChangedCallback` too slow to react? Or ist the `setAttribute` only firing once? Everything else I'm putting in the loop is firing eleven times so the loop seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is because Javascript is single threaded. While your code runs, *nothing else* can run, including callbacks. So the only time the callback has a chance to run at all is when your code finished running, that is after the loop already ended.

There are many resources explaining how the event loop works in more details, for instance I would recommend this video: https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0

Comment: Wow, that is an amazing speech, thank you! However, I still have problems implementing it, I am sorry. MicroTasks won't work because they are executed after the script (but before the event loop), promises will probably (haven't tried that) wait only until the attribute is set, not until the callback is finished. setTimeout doesn't work either.

Comment: I also tried Web Workers, however the file for the code of the Web Worker isn't found. So var worker = new Worker('dataWorker.js'); doesn't work

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You can call the function yourself in the loop instead of trying to work around the very nature of Javascript.

Comment: I see that you're mentioning communicating with a database, but using attributeChangedCallback is absolutely the wrong way to go, that's not at all how attributes are meant to be used.

Comment: What do you mean by "the function" in your first comment? That code snippet has nothing to do with the database. The data from my database is fetched by the function fetchData() at the very beginning. Now, I want to send that data to a Custom Element. The only way in wix, as far as I know, is to set an attribute on that Custom Element, which the Custom Element listens to. After that, I want to print it as a table to the Custom Element's contained page. But I know how to do that last bit. However, I have problems to send the data to the Custom Element.

Comment: I can't send the whole array in one piece, because it seems to be converted to a string by wix. Hence, the output I get is [object Object, object Object]

Comment: An attribute needs to be a string, so if the default string conversion algorithm doesn't work for you, you can use a different, for instance `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Of course! How could I not think of that. Thank you very much! That solves my problem.